# thermodynamics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a problem I've been working with, and I can't seem to get it going. The problem is:

"A bubble rises from the bottom of a lake of depth of 80 m. At this depth the bubble has radius r. The atmospheric pressure is 10^5 Pa. The temperature is constant. At what depth is the bubble's radius equal to 2r? Assume that the water density is 1g/cm^3"

I've been thinking of using the ideal gas law, but I don't how to start. I would appreciate it if someone could guide me through the problem.

(Also sorry for my English, my first language is Swedish)

Thank you!

Comment: If you use the gas law, then you see that at constant temperature the volume (which is related to the radius) depends on the pressure. So, the gas law tells you that you need to find the relation between the pressure and the depth. You can find this relation by considering a small cube shaped volume of water, the top of the cube at depth h, the bottom at depth h + delta h. This cube of water as a weight that follows from the given density. So, gravity acts on it, yet it is stationary. This means that the surrounding water is pushing it upward with the opposite force.

Comment: The pressure at depth h + delta h is a bit higher than the pressure at depth h,  this yields an upward force on the cube which is exactly opposite to the force of gravity. So, this yields the pressure difference over a depth of delta h, the pressure at zero depth is given, so the pressure as a function of the depth follows from this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the hydrostatic equation $p = p_{atm}+\rho g h$, where h is the depth?

Comment: Yeah, I think I've seen it somewhere in the book I'm using, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it in this case. @ChesterMiller

Comment: Just do what Floris indicated in his answer.

Comment: In addition to pressure exerted by water on bubble, there is also pressure increase due to surface tension, so at any height total pressure inside bubble is $p_{atm}+\rho g h+2\sigma /r$, where $\sigma$ is surface tension between air-water interface.

Comment: Although the question is very easy and in falls below the homework category, I think it would be better to leave open, because it is so beautyful. It made my morning better.

Comment: @Zero since the actual radius was not given we have to assume the surface tension effect is supposed to be ignored - although you are right that it exists, and matters especially for small bubbles.

Answer (score 3):

Vetenskap,

You are on the right track, but the ideal gas law takes the temperature as a factor. Instead, use Boyle's law given that the temperature remains constant throughout, i.e.

$$P_1 V_1 = P_2 V_2 $$

Combine this with the hydrostatic equation $$P = P_{atm} + \rho g h$$ as Chester Miller mentioned. Use position 1 as the height below sea level and position 2 as sea level, and you will get your answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The pressure under water increases linearly from 10$^5$ Pa right below the surface to $9\cdot 10^5$ Pa at a depth of 80 m (from 1 atm to 9 atm).

The radius of the bubble doubles from r to 2r - so the volume increases by a factor 8x

Now we know that PV = nRT, and if n and T are constant, it follows that the volume is inversely proportional to the pressure.

So the question you have to solve is - at what depth is the total pressure 1/8 th of the pressure at a depth of 80 m?